Why is Auth0-angular not reading the authentication state
In angular i have in my app component a nav bar like this.
<div class="navbar">
    <button *ngIf="_auth.isAuthenticated$ | async; else outBtn" (click)="_auth.logout()">
      <i class="material-icons">logout</i>
      </button>


<ng-template #outBtn>
  <button (click)="_auth.loginWithPopup()">
    <i class="material-icons">login</i>
    </button>

</ng-template>


</div>

TS
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, public _auth: AuthService) {}
}

and the app module
imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AuthModule.forRoot({
      domain: 'domain',
      clientId: 'client-id',
      authorizationParams: {
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin
      }
    }),

  ]

I was expecting that when the user is not authenticated the login button appears and when they are the logout button appears. The app seems to not be able to read the authentication state and always says the user is not authenticated. Looking at the Auth0 dashboard i could see that the user login is a success. and it I click the login button after I logged in it quickly redirects, so i know the user is logged in.
Why is angular not reading the authentication state ?
-- Edit --
Component
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'andlo';
  currentRoute: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, public _auth: AuthService) {
    this.currentRoute = this.router.url;
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.currentRoute = event.urlAfterRedirects;
      }
    });
    console.log(this.currentRoute)
  }


getRoutes(){
  let activeR = this.router.url;
  console.log(activeR)
}

  navigate(route: string) {
    this.router.navigate([route]);
  }
}

Template
<div class="tab-bar">
  <button [ngClass]="{'active': currentRoute === '/home'}" (click)="navigate('/home')">
    <i class="material-icons">home</i>
  </button>
  
  
    <button *ngIf="_auth.isAuthenticated$ | async; else outBtn" (click)="_auth.logout()">
      <i class="material-icons">logout</i>
      </button>


<ng-template #outBtn>
  <button (click)="_auth.loginWithPopup()">
    <i class="material-icons">login</i>
    </button>

</ng-template>


</div>


You are missing the import CommonModule, that contains the directives like *ngIf or *ngFor, import this into AppModule and it should work.
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
...

...
imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CommonModule, // <- changed here!
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AuthModule.forRoot({
      domain: 'domain',
      clientId: 'clientId',
      authorizationParams: {
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin
      }
    }),
]
...

App Component
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'andlo';
  currentRoute: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, public _auth: AuthService) {
    this.currentRoute = this.router.url;
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.currentRoute = event.urlAfterRedirects;
      }
    });
    console.log(this.currentRoute)
  }


getRoutes(){
  let activeR = this.router.url;
  console.log(activeR)
}

  navigate(route: string) {
    this.router.navigate([route]);
  }
}

Template
<div class="tab-bar">
  <button [ngClass]="{'active': currentRoute === '/home'}" (click)="navigate('/home')">
    <i class="material-icons">home</i>
  </button>
 
    <button *ngIf="_auth.isAuthenticated$ | async; else outBtn" (click)="_auth.logout()">
      <i class="material-icons">logout</i>
      </button>


<ng-template #outBtn>
  <button (click)="_auth.loginWithPopup()">
    <i class="material-icons">login</i>
    </button>

</ng-template>


</div>


That's not it. I have the module imported.

@almostasnecessary please share navbar.com.ts

I edited the question. the navbar is not standalone. its built in the app.component

@almostasnecessary I can't see anything won't could you share GitHub repo?

I dont have the repo. I just posted the whole thing. even my credentials are included :D

I accidentally edited your answer instead of mine. Can you remove the edit i made to yours ? I have edited my question, please check again.

@almostasnecessary please commit the code to github and share the link, it saves me the time of setting up the entire thing, to mimic your environment.

I figure it out. It works fine now.

@almostasnecessary Do post the answer, so that it helps someone!
